# How do I create A joined table in Laravel Migration?

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent, migration

I have a users table with the following columns with User model has one to many relationship with phone model.

**create_users_table.php**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Then I have a phones table, which has a foreign key of user_id
**create_phones_table.php**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('phones', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

**My User Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Phone;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * Define Relationship
     */

    public function phones()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Phone::class);
    }
}
```

**My Phone Model**

```
<?php

    namespace App;

    use App\User;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Phone extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'phones';
    protected $fillable = ['phone' , 'user_id'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

I would like to have a third table in my database call phone_user_table.php. Something like a pivot table where I have joined the user table and phone table where I can see all the records. This is my code where I attempt to join the table.

**create_phone_user.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePhoneUser extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('phone_user', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('phone_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('phone_id')->references('id')->on('phones')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();

            $table 
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'phone_user.user_id')
            ->join('phones', 'phones.id', '=', 'phone_user.phone_id')
            ->select('phone_user.*', 'users.name', 'phones.phone')
            ->get();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('phone_user');
    }
}
```

However, it seems to be giving Base Table phones already exist.

Appreciate all the help given.

Thank you.

Comment: Confirm me that  your migration has been done successfully?

Comment: Laravel Migration using join so please use "Pivot Table". Follow this link https://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/introducing-laravel-many-to-many-relations/

Comment: what are you attempting to do by calling `join` on the `Blueprint` object?

Comment: a phone can belongs to a single user and user have many phone numbers. `users` and `phones` tables are enough for your need. why you need a pivot table here??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon I am aware that you can use relationship to get the data, but i am trying to figure out how does join work in laravel with a third table combining the users and phone table

Comment: @abdullAlmamum the migrations werent successful in the third table because i keep getting a foreign key constraint incorrect, hence i am going to remove the foreign key

Comment: @rockerstechnology does this work with one to many relationship as well?

Comment: @lagbox i am trying to create a joined table called phone_user which is a combination of user and phone table, i am not sure if this is correct

Comment: You are getting that error due to this `$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();` in the `create_phones_table.php` migration. Change it to `$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')`.

Comment: you can join two tables later when querying them. in the schema you can't just join them and make a query here. does it make any sense??

Comment: @zahidhassanemon Thank you. But actually what is the reason that we cant join them in the schema?

Answer (score 3):

This is how it works base on [Laravel Many to Many Relationship Docs.](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

**First**

You need to create 2 `model` that you would like to have relationship.

> In your example you have **USER** and **PHONE** relationship.

In your **User Model** you need to declare the relationship like this:

```
public function phones() {
  return $this->belongsToMany(Phone::Class);
}
```

And In your **Phone Model** you can do like this:

```
public function users() {
  return $this->belongsToMany(User::Class);
}
```

**SECOND**

You need to have 3 `migration` one is for the `user`, `phone` and also the `phone_user`. So it should be look like this.

**Phone User Migration**

```
Schema::create('phone_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('id');
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('phone_id')->index();
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->index();
  $table->timestamps();

  $table->foreign('phone_id')->references('id')->on('phones')->onDelete('cascade');
  $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

> Note: You don't need to have the unsignedBigInteger in both `user` and `phone` `migration`.

When you have a `user list` and a `phone list` you can now assign the `phone` to the `user` like this:

**Controller**

```
$user = User::find(1);
$phone = Phone::find(1);

$user->phones()->attach($phone);
```